# How to automatically update POM versions using GitHub Actions?

Tags: maven, github

Our repositories typically have two branches, `dev` and `main`. The POM version in `dev` is a snapshot, e.g. `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. What I'd like to do is when the PR from `dev` to `main` is merged, the version of the POM in `main` becomes `1.0.0` and the version in `dev` goes up one notch to `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Is it possible? I was looking at the Maven Release plugin, but couldn't quite figure out how to update the version in a different branch. Any ideas?

Comment: Either go with the suggestion of @JFabianMeier or you can do such things via maven-release-plugin...

Answer (score 0):

With `versions:set`, you can set a new version for the POM. Of course, you need to calculate that version first, e.g. using a short script in python or perl.

For more information about the version maven plugin, see:

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can set the version of the POM, the question is, how do I set it in a different branch? I.e. if my action runs on the main branch, how do I update the dev from it?

Comment: I am not familiar with the details of GitHub Actions, but in case of doubt, just check out the other branch, change what you need to change and commit it again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [gitflow-maven-plugin](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin), works quite well and does everything I need!